# MySql Join Tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables,
 jos_messages => 'message_id (PK)', 'message', 'from_user_id', 'touser id'

jos_message_thread => 'thread_id PK','message_id FK', 'from_user_id', 'to_user_id'

jos_users = > 'user_id(FK)', 'firstname', 'avatar'

I need to make a query with this tables to return the data in one result, data are: 
last inserted message (jos_messages), firstname and avatar of message sender (jos_users)
the result should be something like this:

message: "Hi, this is last inserted messsage"

firstname:"ledif"

avatar:"http://a.com/a.png"

What I have now is this query but the problem is, the returned message is not the last message inserted.

```
SELECT jmt.from_user_id, jm.message, ju.firstname, ju.avatar
FROM jos_messages_thread AS jmt
LEFT JOIN jos_messages AS jm ON jm.message_id = jmt.message_id
LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler AS ju ON ju.user_id =     jmt.from_user_id
WHERE jmt.to_user_id ='$user_id'
AND jmt.thread_owner ='$user_id'
GROUP BY jmt.from_user_id
```

Is there a way to ORDER the jm.message_id in the middle of left join query? to make it something like:

```
LEFT JOIN jos_messages AS jm ON jm.message_id = (LAST INSERTED) jmt.message_id
```

Thanks!! btw Im not good in english, Im sorry if my question is not so clear.

Comment: Is the message_id auto incremented?? if so then the last inserted message would be the one with the greatest id

Comment: @Hunter McMillen yeah it is. that was what im expecting, but it did not happen.

Comment: you also need to include an `ORDER BY` statement then. If you do `ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1` that will give you the largest id

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert the ORDER BY in the middle of the join, even if there were a way to do that. Just `ORDER BY jm.message_id DESC` at the end of the whole query, and use `LIMIT 1` to limit the result to the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN jos_messages AS jm ON jm.message_id = (Select jthread.message_id from jos_messages_thread Order By jthread.message_id desc Limit 1)
```